# Update 12.04.4 LTS without uninstall CUDA 6

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, updates, cuda

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.4 and, in my academic projects, i need that OS have CUDA 6 installed. In this moment, Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and CUDA 6 work fine together.
But on last days, when i try to update Ubuntu, new packages will REMOVE CUDA 6. Look:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:

cuda cuda-6-0 cuda-documentation-6-0 cuda-samples-6-0 cuda-toolkit-6-0 freeglut3-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglfw-dev libglu1-mesa-dev

The following NEW packages will be installed:

libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxdamage-dev libxxf86vm-dev >x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev

The following packages will be upgraded:

bluez bluez-alsa bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer dpkg dpkg-dev firefox firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer gnome-settings-daemon libbluetooth3 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libdpkg-perl libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libglu1-mesa libkms1 libmtdev1 libpciaccess0 linux-firmware linux-libc-dev >mesa-common-dev mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra nvidia-331-dev nvidia-331-uvm
thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us unity-greeter x11-apps xserver-common

38 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 9 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Need to get 95.8 MB of archives.

After this operation, 363 MB disk space will be freed.

Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n

Abort.
```

I would like to update my Ubuntu 12.04.4 without uninstall CUDA 6. How i do this?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you install CUDA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like something in the `nvidia` and `mesa` upgrades is conflicting with `cuda`.

You can do a simple `apt-get upgrade`, which should not ask to remove anything, only do what upgrades can be done without removing anything.

To investigate why `cuda` is being removed, you can try upgrading the remaining packages (after `apt-get upgrade`) one at a time and see which one is removing `cuda`. You can use `synaptic` to graphically do this, or simply do `apt-get install <package>` to upgrade a single package (`install` will upgrade packages if possible).

It's possible that you can just proceed with removing it and then reinstall it after the upgrade, but it's better to know ahead of time what packages are conflicting.

You can get CUDA here if needed.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads